# responseText - XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

in my code responseText is not working. It is supposed to display, text entered in the text box +" :Your request has been seen by syam"

```
<html>
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlHttpRequest;
            function sSignature(str) {

                xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {                
                        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML =    xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "AjaxResponse.aspx?q=" + str, true);
                xmlHttpRequest.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
            enter a string :<input type="text" id="textbox" onkeyup="sSignature(this.value)"/>
            <span id="target">text should change here</span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the code-behind page, in page_load()

```
string sRequest = Request.QueryString["q"];
var sResponse = sRequest+ " :Your request has been seen by syam";
Response.Write(sResponse);
```

Comment: Can you do better than "Not working"? What does the Net traffic inspector say? Are there errors in the console? Did you try to see how far in the code it goes before it bugs out?

Comment: it is giving an error in the line when readystate is 4 document.getElementById("target").innerHTML =    xmlHttpRequest.responseText;

Comment: check your code-behind page, is there you getting query string successfully

Comment: You should get the responsetText from a callback only..I think so

Comment: This worked for me with PHP back-end. `$sRequest = $_GET["q"];
$sResponse = $sRequest . " :Your request has been seen by syam";
echo $sResponse;`. So please check your ASP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the error is in your `onreadystatechangedhandler`. It will receive an `event` param, in which the `target` property points to the XHR-instance.

Try swapping it out with this:

```
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    var xhr = event.target;

    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = xhr.responseText
    }
};
```

Comment: change `xhr.responseCode` to `xhr.status`

Answer (score 1):

send your request first

```
function sSignature(str) {

    xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", "AjaxResponse.jsp?q=" + str, true);
    xmlHttpRequest.send();
    xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {                
            document.getElementById("target").innerHTML =    xmlHttpRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Mind that your code will not work in Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Secondly, modify one line of code to make it look better -

`xhr.send()` by `xhr.send(null);`

Comment: Why use `xhr.send(null)` instead of `xhr.send()`?