# Capture form response in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Let say I submit data to a form with the following code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(), formData = new FormData();  
formData.append("img", img);
formData.append("user", localStorage["username"]);
formData.append("pass", localStorage["password"]);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
       var value = xhr.responseText; // value should equal "1234"
        alert( "value = " + value );
    }else{
    alert("none");
}
};
xhr.open("POST", "http://joubin.me/uploads3/upload_file.php", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

After upload.php is done, it redirects to another page called giveid.php and the only thing it displays is a text string with an id

say `1234`

How can I with javascript capture this exact id.

Keep in mind, a different upload.php redirect will have a different id number on giveid.php?

I looked into the [xmlhtml](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp) responses and could not figure it out.

Here is what form goes

```
$password = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$username =  $_REQUEST['user'];
$image = $_REQUEST['img'];
echo $password;
echo "<br/>";
echo $username;
echo "<br/>";
echo $image;
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","ya","right");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        echo "could not connect";
  }
$asql = "SELECT * FROM `ashkan`.`users` where user='$username' and pass='$password';";

$result = mysql_query($asql);
echo $result;
// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

echo $count;

echo 11;
if($count == 1){
$sql = "INSERT INTO `ashkan`.`goog` (`user`, `pass`, `img`) VALUES ('$username', '$passwo$
}
mysql_query($sql);
mysql_close($con);
header( 'Location: giveid.php' ) ;
```

and here is the content of giveid.php

```
1234
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: is there a reason you're not using a JavaScript library such as jQuery for handling ajax requests?

Comment: There is no need of reinventing the wheel. Use `$.post(url,fn)`

Comment: Yes, as I understand, Chrome extensions do not support jQuery

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709733/responsetext-xmlhttprequest

Comment: jQuery is not a solution for someone who wants to understand how it works

Comment: @LarryBattle I want to, if possible, add to my code and I dont fully understand whats going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `xhr.onreadystatechange` to retrieve the response from the server.

Something like this might work.

```
var value;
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("img", img);
formData.append("user", localStorage.username);
formData.append("pass", localStorage.password);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        value = xhr.responseText; // value should equal "1234"
        alert( "value = " + value );
    }
};
xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Info Here: http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php

Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent. So get rid of all the echos you have in the php file. Once you echo then that starts the output buffer for the response to the client.

Info Here: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php

I think this should be your only echo on the php page.

```
echo include( 'giveid.php');
```

Try using Google Chrome Dev Tool Network tab to view the response from your php webpage.

- Launch Google Chrome,
- Hit f12,
- Click the network tab,
- reload your page,
- click on the ajax response page,
- click preview to view the response.

Info Here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: That 1234 value is being displayed as text on a regular html page. is that what this is getting?

Comment: @user1048138: XMLHttpRequest stores whatever the server returns in responseText. If it is a plain string "1234" then it is the string "1234". If it is an HTML page (which is just a bunch of strings BTW) with the 'word' 1234 then it will be the string "<html><body>1234</body></html>" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

[xhr documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/)

Get xhr.response then parse it.

We usually return a json string so js can parse it easily.

[googled xhr example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)
something like this:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState!=4 || xhr.status!=200)
        return;
    var resp = xhr.responseText;
    var parsed = eval(resp);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats my question, however, I dont know how to capture this specific response. Could you elaborate.