# responseText is not displaying anything

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, httpresponse

I'm playing around a little with Ajax and i'm using the following code.

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("POST", "pythonTesting.php", true);
r.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (r.readyState === 4 && r.status === 200) {
        alert("Success: " + r.responseText);
    }
};
r.send("text=yellow");
```

It is successful but the alert isn't showing the actual `responseText`.

pythonTesting.php (not to be confused by the name) is just:

```
 <?php
   echo $_POST['text'];
 ?>
```

I'm expecting the `responseText` to be `yellow` because that's how I sent it but its not. I'm not really seeing what the problem is though. It must be one of those easy to fix mistakes.

Comment: you've mistyped `responseText` a couple times along the question but your code block looks fine.

Comment: What's the response of pythonTesting.php in firebug? Blank?

Comment: @Shawn31313 what if you call the page separately using querystring? does that show the output?

Comment: @greener Yes. It shows output.

Comment: And when I use jQuery.ajax it works just fine. But this way I can't seem to get to work.

Comment: @akonsu It just shows: "Success: "

Comment: is this relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709733/responsetext-xmlhttprequest ?

Comment: @akonsu Hmm, I thought for sure that answer was going to fix this issue /: But there is still blank.

Comment: In the dev on chrome it is telling me: "This request has no response data available"

Comment: what happens if you issue a GET and in php just emit a string? looks like something with your PHP setup.

Comment: @akonsu It works. There is something i'm doing wrong with that `send` function.

Comment: did you try setting the application/x-www-form-urlencoded header in the request?

Comment: No, how would I do that. I see that when I use jQuery.ajax in thier `POST` they do something with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

Comment: Thank you, That worked. I didn't know you have to set a special header for PHP. But I do see it now on w3schools.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a post I believe you will need to set the length:

```
r.setRequestHeader("Content-length", "text=yellow".length);
```

Comment: No Luck with that either. +1 for the try(:

Answer (score 0):

send the variables through the address:

```
r.open("POST", "pythonTesting.php?text=yellow", true);
```

then retrieve the variable in php by

```
$text = $_REQUEST['text'];
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the answer but as you can see there already has been a solution to the problem. This is the answer with the check mark.