# Should the onreadystatechange callback always receive an event parameter?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

In the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) their example of the `onreadystatechange` callback receives no param

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    method = "GET",
    url = "https://developer.mozilla.org/";

xhr.open(method, url, true);
// no param!
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
// the response would be found on the xhr instance
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
xhr.send();
```

However, I have seen [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8710225/4769440) that the response will be found in an event parameter passed to the callback

```
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    var xhr = event.target;

    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = xhr.responseText
    }
};
```

I've come across some edge cases where the parent object does matter. In some cases, the `onreadystatechange` callback parameter has no `responseText` property but the xml instance does.

Questions:

1. Do headers have anything to do with this discrepancy?
2. Is there a canonical, bulletproof way of accessing the `responseText` property, either from the callback parameter or the xml instance? It would be easy to add logic that checks both objects but I'm wondering if there's some option I have to set in on the xmlhttpreq instance.